# Rails - Bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Encountered a problem when I tried to run/check bundle on on Mac
Bundler/bundler are in the local gem list when I did gem list --local

Gem env returns the following

```
 RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
      - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - universal-darwin-14
      - GEM PATHS:
         - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
         - /Users/jenny0322/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
         - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
      - GEM CONFIGURATION:
         - :update_sources => true
         - :verbose => true
         - :backtrace => false
         - :bulk_threshold => 1000
      - REMOTE SOURCES:
         - https://rubygems.org/
```

Echo Path returns

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

which gem returns

```
/usr/bin/gem
```

How do I add path to the directory? I tried

```
export PATH ="/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

and have no luck...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It seems that **[Bundler](http://bundler.io/)** is not installed in your machine.

You have to **install bundler first** for that.

**1:** `gem install bundler`

**2:** `bundle install`

Hope this help you !!!

Answer (score 1):

Open a new terminal window and run:

`gem install bundler`

Then, try again.

See the [documentation](http://bundler.io/).